# confusing usage of bind in openlayers library source code

Tags: bind, openlayers-5

I am looking into the source code of the `openlayers` javascript library. And in the file of `source/CartoDB.js`, I find there is something as following:

```
class CartoDB extends XYZ {
  constructor () {}
  initializeMap_() {
    ...
    const client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.addEventListener('load', this.handleInitResponse_.bind(this, paramHash));
    client.addEventListener('error', this.handleInitError_.bind(this));
    client.open('POST', mapUrl);
    client.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    client.send(JSON.stringify(this.config_));
  }

  handleInitResponse_(paramHash, event) {
    ...
  }

  handleInitError_(event) {
    ...
  } 
}
```

I clean the code and remove the unrelated code for my question. 
My confusing point is the following two lines:

```
client.addEventListener('load', this.handleInitResponse_.bind(this, paramHash));
client.addEventListener('error', this.handleInitError_.bind(this));
```

I think `this.handleInitResponse_.bind(this, paramHash)` just equals to `this.handleInitResponse_` and `this.handleInitError_.bind(this)` just equals to `this.handleInitError_`. And these two methods are just defined in the CartoDB class.

So why handle it like this?

Comment: It's being used as an xhr callback where by default `this` is the xhr request.

Comment: which `this` are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's comparable with these two scenarios

```
var myObject = {
    readyState: "myObject",
    errorHandler: function() { console.log(this.readyState) },
    initialize: function() {
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.addEventListener('error',this.errorHandler);
       xhr.open("GET", "http://invalid.com/invalid.dat", true);
       xhr.send();
    }
}
myObject.initialize(); // logs "4"

var myObject = {
    readyState: "myObject",
    errorHandler: function() { console.log(this.readyState) },
    initialize: function() {
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.addEventListener('error',this.errorHandler.bind(this));
       xhr.open("GET", "http://invalid.com/invalid.dat", true);
       xhr.send();
    }
}
myObject.initialize(); // logs "myObject"
```

Comment: thank you, it's clear now. In the scope of the callback function, `this` is `xhr`.